# How can I make a site map that specifies dynamic routes?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, xml, sitemap

So, I have a few dynamic routes that I want a search engine to try to index.
For example, `/post/:id`, where `:id` is the post's ID.
How can I implement this with a sitemap?

Answer (score 0):

**URLs in a sitemap can't include RegExp, [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), or similar patterns.**
You will have to write your own sitemap generator or use a third party.

- All these posts are stored in a DB, right?
  Therefore, `SELECT link_id FROM posts_table` from the DB;
- Merge everything into the sitemap file;
- Send a spec GET requests (ping) to the desired search engines.

THEN run it every hour or once a day etc. (u can use [cron](https://crontab.guru/) for this)

NOTE:

- Don't forget to encode each URL (u can use "[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)" for this);
- Be sure to monitor broken links;
- Use only canonical URLs;
- Very large sitemaps (~50,000 links), it is better to divide into smaller sitemaps.

Comment: I've heard that HTML pages can work as a sitemap too. is that correct? So, I can map out links to every post and every comment,  on that specific HTML page? Like how Apple has this https://www.apple.com/in/sitemap/

Comment: Yes and no. HTML can hypothetically be the summary page of all links, accordingly, the search engine that will crawl on this page will get everything you need to index your site. But this is not a canonical sitemap. It's best to [use xml, as Apple does](https://www.apple.com/sitemap.xml). The html page is rather human-readable.

Comment: Would it make more sense to have a sitemap that has a lot of hardcoded stuff, as well as a link to the HTML page that has all the links that are being fetched from my express server?

Comment: Should an HTML map, with a bunch of links, be added to the list of canonical sitemap? - Yes, why not.
Into the sitemap, you need to add all the [canonical links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) of your site, to pages with unique content, which you would like to see in search engines.